# EntityType "CompanyNames" has no key defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I can't update my DB in Package Manager Console, because I'm getting these two errors:
EntityType 'CompanyNames' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
EntitySet 'CompanyNames' is based on type 'CompanyNames' that has no keys defined.

I read solutions, that in my model class I need to put [Key] atribute, but nothing changed.

My model class:

```
public class CompanyNames {
      [Key]
      public int CompanyID;
      public string Name;
}
```

My Initial class:

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration {
      public override void Up() {
      .....
      //Some code here
      CreateTable (
          "dbo.CompanyNames",
          c => new {
              CompanyID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
              Name = c.String(), })
              .PrimaryKey(t => t.CompanyID);
      }
}
```

And then in Configuration.cs I put some code to Seed method to fill the table

```
context.CompanyNames.AddOrUpdate(p => p.CompanyID,
        new CompanyNames {
            CompanyID = 12345,
            Name = "Microsoft"
        ),
        //.... and so on
```

Can any one help me with this problem?

Comment: add primary key to table

Comment: doesn't PrimaryKey(t => t.CompanyID); adds primary key?

Comment: try in SQL add primary key to table.
in table Designer

Comment: I can't find the table in table designer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your fields properties with getter and setter.

Comment: Yeah, just before I read your solution I noticed that and now it works :)